# Getting IndexError: list index out of range when calculating Euclidean distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, euclidean-distance

I am trying to apply the code provided at https://towardsdatascience.com/3-basic-distance-measurement-in-text-mining-5852becff1d7 . When I use this with my own data I seem to access a part of list that does not exist, and just not able to identify where I am making this error:

```
File "D:/Proj/projects/eucledian_1/nltk_headline_1.py", line 190, in eucledian
    score = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]])[0][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't think I am exceeding the length of `only_event` or 'transformed_results'. This is the code that I have:

```
def eucledian(self):
        print('inside eucledian', only_event) 
        for i, news_headline in enumerate(only_event): # range(len(only_event))
            print('*******', only_event[i])
            print('this is transformed results: ', transformed_results[i]) # prints
            score = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]])[0][0]
            print('-----', only_event[i]) # prints
            print('Score: %.2f, Comparing Sentence: %s' % (score, news_headline)) # prints
```

The data, which I am able to read from DB and store in the list `only_event`(length = 2) look as below:
`['Perhaps this code is incomplete or mistyped in some way.', 'Use one of the following methods:\n* Ensure that the power is turned on.\n* Only concatenate a user-supplied value into a query, or if it must be a Boolean or numeric type.\n']`.

The print statements give the output, but line invoking euclidean_distances is throwing the `IndexError: list index out of range` error. The `transformed_results` (length = 1) look like this:

```
[array([329.,   2.,  57.,  44.,  44.,  44.,  88.,  57.,  44.,  44.,  44.,
        57.,  13.,  13.,  88.,   1.,   2.,  13., 136.,  13.,  13.,  13.,
       220.,  44.,  44.,  44.,  88.,  88.,  44.,  44.,  89.,   2.,  13.,
        88.,  13.,  44., 132.,  26.,   4.,   4., 132.,  44.,   1.,  13.,
        48.,  27.,  88., 132.,  88.,  44.,  44., 132.,  13.,   4.,  13.,
        44.,  13., 158.,  15.,  13., 162.,   4.,  44.,  44.,  26.,  13.,
         1.,  44.,   1.,  57.,  13.,   1.,  44.,  44.,  45.,  44.,  44.,
         4.,  13.,  44.,   1.,  13.,  44.,  44.,  44.,  44., 336.,  44.,
        51.,   2., 235.,  13., 132., 132.,  70.,  26.,  44.,  13.,  13.,
        13.,  44.,   4.,   1.,  57.,  44.,  44.,   2.,  44.])]
```

Thank you in advance for looking through this

**Updated to include a reproducible code @dzang**

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.preprocessing
import sklearn.metrics

token_event_obj = ['perhaps', 'this', 'code', 'is', 'incomplete', 'or', 'mistyped', 'in', 'some', 'way', 'use', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'following', 'methodsn', 'use', 'a', 'querypreparation', 'api', 'to', 'safely', 'construct', 'the', 'sql', 'query', 'containing', 'usersupplied', 'valuesn', 'only', 'concatenate', 'a', 'usersupplied', 'value', 'into', 'a', 'query', 'if', 'it', 'has', 'been', 'checked', 'against', 'a', 'whitelist', 'of', 'safe', 'string', 'values', 'or', 'if', 'it', 'must', 'be', 'a', 'boolean', 'or', 'numeric', 'typen']
only_event = ['Perhaps this code is incomplete or mistyped in some way.', 'Use one of the following methods:\n* Use a query-preparation API to safely construct the SQL query containing user-supplied values.\n* Only concatenate a user-supplied value into a query if it has been checked against a whitelist of safe string values, or if it must be a Boolean or numeric type.\n']

def transform(headlines):
    print('inside transform', headlines)
    tokens = [w for s in headlines for w in s]
    print()
    print('All Tokens:')
    print(tokens)

    results = []
    label_enc = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    onehot_enc = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()

    encoded_all_tokens = label_enc.fit_transform(list(set(tokens)))
    encoded_all_tokens = encoded_all_tokens.reshape(len(encoded_all_tokens), 1)

    onehot_enc.fit(encoded_all_tokens)

    for headline_tokens in headlines:
        print()
        print(headline_tokens)
        print('Original Input:', headline_tokens)

        encoded_words = label_enc.transform(headline_tokens)
        print('Encoded by Label Encoder:', encoded_words)

        encoded_words = onehot_enc.transform(encoded_words.reshape(len(encoded_words), 1))
        print('Encoded by OneHot Encoder:')
        # print(encoded_words)

        results.append(np.sum(encoded_words.toarray(), axis=0))
        print('Transform results:', results)

    return results


def eucledian():
        print('inside eucledian', len(only_event))
        for i, news_headline in enumerate(only_event): # range(len(only_event))
            print('*******', only_event[i])
            print('this is transformed results: ', transformed_results)
            # print('len', len(sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]])[0]))
            print(type(transformed_results), len(transformed_results))
            score = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]])[0]
            print('-----', only_event[i])
            print('Score: %.2f, Comparing Sentence: %s' % (score, news_headline))


transformed_results = transform([token_event_obj])
eucledian()
```

Comment: the IndexError could also come from the last `[0][0]` that you are using. Can you print `len(sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]]))` and `len(sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]])[0])` ? What do you get?

Comment: The output of both equal to 1. When I run the code with the above snippet, I still get the same error: `score = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances([transformed_results[i]], [transformed_results[0]])
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: can you share your script or give a reproducible example?
what is transformed_results? When and how are you computing it?
The error is clear, you are trying to access an element of a list that is not there.
What is `len(transformed_results)`?

Comment: Yes, a runnable code giving the same error will help diagnose better. The code above runs as-is and give the same error

Comment: @dzang if I use `transformed_results = transform([token_event_obj, token_event_obj, token_event_obj, token_event_obj])` or a list of four strings i.e. `len(transformed_results) = 4` then there are no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the example you provide is in the fact that `transformed_results` is a list with one element, holding the tokenized sentence 1.

`only_event` though has 2 sentences, and you are using that to provide `i`. So `i` will be `0` and `1`. When `i` is `1`, `transformed_results[i]` raises the error.

If you tokenize both sentences in `only_event`, for example with:

```
headlines = [''.join([c for c in s.replace('\n', '').lower() if c not in ['.', '*', ':', '-']]).split() for s in only_event]
```

which gives:

> [['perhaps', 'this', 'code', 'is', 'incomplete', 'or', 'mistyped', 'in', 'some', 'way'], ['use', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'following', 'methods', 'use', 'a', 'querypreparation', 'api', 'to', 'safely', 'construct', 'the', 'sql', 'query', 'containing', 'usersupplied', 'values', 'only', 'concatenate', 'a', 'usersupplied', 'value', 'into', 'a', 'query', 'if', 'it', 'has', 'been', 'checked', 'against', 'a', 'whitelist', 'of', 'safe', 'string', 'values,', 'or', 'if', 'it', 'must', 'be', 'a', 'boolean', 'or', 'numeric', 'type']]

then `transformed_results` will have length 2 as well.

And you will compare the euclidean distance of both sentences, including the reference sentence with itself.

Comment: Yes, Your explanation on the lengths of `transformed_results` and `only_event` solved it. I tried with `[[i] for i in only_event]` to create a list of lists and it works. If possible, can you please explain what your does? It seems to remove \n, converts to lowercase and what's the role of the not in?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @mamat.mj it's a very ugly one-liner to tokenize your sentence. So indeed, remove `\n` put every word to lower case, then loop through each character and build a list of characters (excluding `['.', '*', ':', '-']`, that's the role of the `if not`) then it joins the list of characters back into a string and splits it on the spaces, to obtain words without punctuation and capitals. I am not familiar with tokenization but there will be libraries to carry that out properly. My solution was just a quick and dirty line to get the example.